# Using ArcGIS to get flood zone data for GPS coordinates in JS

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am new to using the ArcGIS API and need to return some simple data from a query using JS. From what I can tell, I need to query the Feature Layer by using Spatial coordinates. However, I get zero results back when I try to do this.

What I need to be able to do is obtain the Longitude and Latitude coordinates from the user, and then do a lookup of which flood zone those coordinates are located in.

I'm using the CDN since this is a web app, and this is the code I have tried so far. I'm sure I'm way off, so could somebody point me in the right direction?

**Note**: I removed my API key for obvious reasons. Also, the feature layer I'm querying is the Abstract layer because I'm testing pulling the AbstractID from the query right now.

In the HTML markup I have this defined:

```
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@('@')esri/arcgis-rest-request@4.0.0/dist/bundled/request.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@('@')esri/arcgis-rest-feature-service@4.0.0/dist/bundled/feature-service.umd.js"></script>
```

And then in the javascript, I have this:

```
const apiKey = "MY-API-KEY";
const authentication = arcgisRest.ApiKeyManager.fromKey(apiKey);

const queryGeometry = {
    x: -95.36243884,
    y: 29.75351391,
    spatialReference: {
        wkid: 4326
    }
};

function GetGisAbstractData() {
    arcgisRest
        .queryFeatures({
            url: "https://services1.arcgis.com/PRoAPGnMSUqvTrzq/arcgis/rest/services/Abstract/FeatureServer/0",
            geometry: queryGeometry,
            geometryType: "esriGeometryPoint",
            spatialRel: "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
            authentication
        })
        .then((response) => {
            document.getElementById("sample").textContent = JSON.stringify(response.features, null, 2);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of the coordinates and the abstract data layer the results are correct, there is no data at that location. Try adjusting the y coordinate to 30.190 as there is abstract data at this location, you can test your queries at the rest endpoint https://services1.arcgis.com/PRoAPGnMSUqvTrzq/arcgis/rest/services/Abstract/FeatureServer/0/query